# How to inject constant from gulp-ng-config to another constant in angular app?

Tags: angularjs

Currently I had maintained the constants in the project as angular constant. In order to implement environment variables, I have integrated gulp-ng-config.

Now, I cant seem to inject the environment variable into my existing app constant.

```
// Environment based constant from "gulp-ng-config"

(function () { 
 return angular.module('myApp.config', [])
.constant('EnvironmentConfig', {"hostUrl":"http://localhost:3002/"});
})();



// Existing constant file

var Resources = function () {
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3002/';
return {
   URLS: {
   books: baseURL + 'books/'
    }
  }
}
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .constant('RESOURCES', Resources());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the `myApp.config` module into your `myApp` module:

```
module('myApp', ['myApp.config'])
```

This is outlined in [the project README](https://github.com/ajwhite/gulp-ng-config/blob/develop/README.md):

> We now can include this configuration module in our main app and access the constants

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.config']).run(function (string) {
  console.log("The string constant!", string) // outputs "my string"
});
```

Perhaps it's not clear enough. I'll look at updating that into a clearer step-by-step instruction.

Sorry for the late response!